# Managing Large amounts of Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, data-management

I'm currently in the process of making an App using Javascroipt and Phonegap that needs to save a Database or something similar localy while offline until it is later synced with an external Database (not the main Problem).
So whats the best solution for managing relativly big chunks of data that have to be modified a lot during runtime, be able to delete entrys, add new entrys, read entrys using attributes and ids, sort entrys and be able to import and export data in a file (i.e give me a string or object that I can save in a file using phonegap)?
I already looked at TaffyDB (abandonned since 2 years) and pounchDB (seams to work using ajax and therefore require internet connection).

Comment: Can't you use html5 IndexedDB?

Comment: Does this reliable work in Windows Phone, Android and IOS and with alrge amount of data? Or Are there any restrications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good that you have already tried pouchdb.js that is client side implementation of couchdb database and is supported and tested for all the major browsers and platforms.
indexeddb is actually latest web browser standard for storing large chunks of data in the form of objects.

All the major storage libraries including pouchdb are based on this only.

Kindly mark this answer if this is what you need or comment back for more explanations.